# Laravel: Get URL from routes BY NAME

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I'm trying to do something a little different and I couldn't find any way to do it. Maybe my approach is wrong but either way I figured I might find some help here.

I have a Laravel 5 project and you know how you can get the current route name by using:

```
\Request::route()->getName();
```

So I'm actually looking to do the exact opposite. Maybe not the exact opposite but what I need is to retrieve my route URL based on the name that I gave to that route.
Here is my dream scenario.

my **routes.php:**

```
Route::any('/hos', "HospitalController@index")->name("hospital");
```

What I **would like to do** in my controller that I have no idea how to or even if is possible:

```
// I have no idea if this is possible but thats what I'm trying to accomplish
$my_route_url = \Request::route()->getURLByName("hospital");

echo $my_route_url; // this would echo: "/hos"
```

I might be using the wrong approach here so maybe you guys can help me out and shine some light on the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`$url = route('routeName');`

if there is a param

`$url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying  to rename your route into a specify one
 In the web.php file

```
Route::get('anyroute', array('as' => 'newname', function() {
    $url = route('new_name');
    return "This is the $url";    
}));
```